# QProcess to extract files using 7zip in subprocess

Tags: c++, subprocess, 7zip, qprocess

I am trying to use `QProcess` to call `7z.exe` and unzip all `*.zip` and `*.7z` files in a root directory and subdirectories, but it works only in the root directory.

It looks like it also does not have a problem finding the right path to the next archive, but it did not unzip the file.

Output:

> QProcess::start: Process is already running

Can someone help me with this problem?

My code:

**mainwindows.h:**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(&unzip,&QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput,this,&MainWindow::readyReadStandardOutput);
    connect(&unzip,&QProcess::stateChanged,this,&MainWindow::statusChanged);
    connect(ui->startButton,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::startClicked);
    connect(&unzip,&QProcess::errorOccurred,this,&MainWindow::processError);
    connect(&unzip, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),this,&MainWindow::processFinished);
    connect(ui->selectPath,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::selectPathClicked);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::statusChanged(QProcess::ProcessState state){
    switch (state) {
    case QProcess::NotRunning:
        ui->startButton->setText("START");
        this->updateUi(true);
        break;
    case QProcess::Running:
    case QProcess::Starting:
        ui->startButton->setText("STOP");
        this->updateUi(false);
    }
}
void MainWindow::updateUi(bool enable)
{
    ui->pathEdit->setEnabled(enable);
}

void MainWindow::startClicked()
{
    qDebug()<<"Started";
    QStringList arguments;
    QString path=ui->pathEdit->text();
    arguments<<"x"<<path+QDir::separator()+"*.zip"<<"-o"+path+QDir::separator()+"*";
    switch (unzip.state()) {
    case QProcess::NotRunning:
        unzip.setWorkingDirectory(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
        unzip.start("7z.exe",arguments);
        break;
    case QProcess::Running:
    case QProcess::Starting:
        unzip.kill();
        break;
    }
}

void MainWindow::readyReadStandardOutput(){
    ui->logTextEdit->appendPlainText(unzip.readAllStandardOutput());
}

void MainWindow::processError(QProcess::ProcessError error)
{
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Unzip warpper",tr("Error %1 has occured").arg(error));

}

void MainWindow::processFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exit)
{
        switch (exit) {
        case QProcess::CrashExit:
             QMessageBox::critical(this,"Unzip warpper",tr("Unzip process has crashed"));
            break;
        case QProcess::NormalExit:
            break;
        }

        if(ui->checkRecursive->isChecked()){
        QString path=ui->pathEdit->text();
        QDirIterator it(path, QStringList() << "*.zip" << ".7z" ,QDir::Files,  QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
        while(it.hasNext()){
            QString path=it.next();
            qDebug()<<path;
            qDebug()<<exitCode;
            QStringList arguments;
            arguments<<"x"<<path+QDir::separator()+"*.zip"<<"-o"+path+QDir::separator()+"*";
            unzip.start("7z.exe",arguments);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::selectPathClicked()
{
    QString directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,
        tr("Select Direcory to unzip"), "");
    if(!directory.isEmpty()){
        ui->pathEdit->setText(directory);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionQuit_triggered()
{
    unzip.kill();
    QApplication::quit();
}
```

Comment: In the `while(it.hasNext())` loop you're repeatedly starting the `unzip` process without waiting for the previous iteration to finish. You probably only want to start it once here since it will trigger that slot again when it's done.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i tried it and nothing changed.  :/